# Why is Sonar design view not showing any dependencies for my project?

Tags: java, dependencies, sonarqube

I've successfully set up Sonar against a large Java project that is built using Ant. I've finally hooked up the JUnit test results and the Cobertura code coverage report.

I now see all the packages in the design view but there are no values for dependencies between any of the packages or classes (see example below).

[image: No dependencies]

Does anyone have any idea what I have missed here?

**UPDATE**

Looking at the output of the Sonar Ant task I also notice that the package design task is completing very quickly for what is a fairly large and complicated project. From the Ant output:

```
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Package design analysis...
[sonar:sonar] [INFO]  Package design analysis done: 66 ms
```

The Ant task is as follows:

```
<target name="sonar" depends="collate-xml-reports">
    <sonar:sonar workDir="src/build/sonarTemp" key="myProjectKeyWhichHasBeenChangedToHideMyClient" version="1.0" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

        <!-- source directories (required) -->
        <sources>
            <path location="src/common/src" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/src" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/src" />
            <path location="src/nativeLib/src" />
            <path location="src/services/src" />
        </sources>

        <!-- list of properties (optional) -->
        <property key="sonar.projectName" value="RPS Nightly" />
        <property key="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="reuseReports" />
        <property key="sonar.surefire.reportsPath" value="src/reports/junit" />
        <property key="sonar.cobertura.reportPath" value="src/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml" />

        <!-- test source directories (optional) -->
        <tests>
            <path location="src/common/test" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/test" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/test" />
            <path location="src/services/test" />
        </tests>

        <!-- binaries directories, which contain for example the compiled Java bytecode (optional) -->
        <binaries>
            <path location="src/common/build" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/build" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/build" />
            <path location="src/services/build" />
        </binaries>

        <!-- path to libraries (optional). These libraries are for example used by the Java Findbugs plugin -->
        <libraries>
            <path location="src/common/lib/**/" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/lib/**/" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/lib/**/" />
            <path location="src/services/lib/" />
        </libraries>
    </sonar:sonar>
</target>
```

Comment: I use Gradle and I was setting the binaries to "build/classes" however Gradle uses "build/classes/main" as the root for production binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Java n00b it turns out that this was a misunderstanding on my part. The binaries directory locations need to point to the root folder of the compiled Java bytecode but I was pointing it to the jar file location. In this case the bytecode is written to the build/classes folder so I needed to modify my ant target (shown in the question) from:

```
    <binaries>
        <path location="src/common/build" />
        <path location="src/commonWidgets/build" />
        <path location="src/compositionWidget/build" />
        <path location="src/services/build" />
    </binaries>
```

To:

```
    <binaries>
        <path location="src/common/build/classes" />
        <path location="src/commonWidgets/build/classes" />
        <path location="src/compositionWidget/build/classes" />
        <path location="src/services/build/classes" />
    </binaries>
```

This fixed the problem and the design view is now correctly populated.